# Python - Subprocess - How to call a Piped command in Windows?

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, echo, popen

How do I run this command with subprocess?

I tried:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(
    '''ECHO bosco|"C:\Program Files\GNU\GnuPG\gpg.exe" --batch --passphrase-fd 0 --output "c:\docume~1\usi\locals~1\temp\tmptlbxka.txt" --decrypt "test.txt.gpg"''',
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
   stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
)
stdout_value, stderr_value = proc.communicate()
```

but got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
  File "C:\Python24\lib\subprocess.py", line 542, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python24\lib\subprocess.py", line 706, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Errno 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Things I've noticed:

1. Running the command on the windows
   console works fine.
2. If I remove the
   ECHO bosco| part, it runs fine the
   the popen call above.  So I think
   this problem is related to echo or
   |.

Comment: Does that full line actually work when you run it in the Windows console?  WindowsError suggests that the problem is not your Python code, but the actual command to be executed.

Comment: Yes, it runs from the windows dos console.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First and foremost, you don't actually need a pipe; you are just sending input. You can use [subprocess.communicate](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) for that.

Secondly, don't specify the command as a string; that's messy as soon as filenames with spaces are involved.

Thirdly, if you really wanted to execute a piped command, just call the shell. On Windows, I believe it's `cmd /c program name arguments | further stuff`.

Finally, single back slashes can be dangerous: `"\p"` is `'\\p'`, but `'\n'` is a new line. Use [os.path.join()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) or [os.sep](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.sep) or, if specified outside python, just a forward slash.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(
    ['C:/Program Files/GNU/GnuPG/gpg.exe',
    '--batch', '--passphrase-fd', '0',
    '--output ', 'c:/docume~1/usi/locals~1/temp/tmptlbxka.txt',
    '--decrypt', 'test.txt.gpg',],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
   stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
)
stdout_value, stderr_value = proc.communicate('bosco')
```

Answer (score 4):

You were right, the ECHO is the problem. Without the shell=True option the ECHO command cannot be found.

This fails with the error you saw:

```
subprocess.call(["ECHO", "Ni"])
```

This passes: prints Ni and a 0

```
subprocess.call(["ECHO", "Ni"], shell=True)
```

Comment: actually, shouldn't this be `subprocess.call("ECHO Ni", shell=True)` ? and `subprocess.call(["ECHO", "Ni"])` works fine for me.

Comment: You can use either but according to the [Popen Constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor)
 docs: “Unless otherwise stated, it is recommended to pass args as a sequence.”