# python: why does calling echo with subprocess return WindowsError 2?

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

In my program, I have a function runScript():

```
def runScript():
subprocess.call(['echo', 'hello'])
```

I have seen many similar examples in the Python documentation, so I assumed this would work.  However, when I call this function in my program, it returns a WindowsError.

```
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Why does this happen?  How can I fix it?

Comment: echo is a linux command. Run this on a linux machine and it will work flawlessly.

Comment: @Flo it is also a Windows shell command.

Comment: @JoeFish Indeed. My mistake. Reading kindall's answer makes a lot of sense. I don't know why I jumped to say that. Maybe I wanted linux to be more exclusive. :P

Comment: @flo if it makes you feel any better, I thought the same at first but opened a Windows shell and tried it before posting :)

Comment: @JoeFish I'm on a linux box :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python - Subprocess - How to call a Piped command in Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046474/python-subprocess-how-to-call-a-piped-command-in-windows)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `echo` command is built in to the Windows shell, `cmd.exe`. It is not an external program that can be called without the shell. Therefore, your `subprocess.call()` needs to specify `shell=True`.

```
subprocess.call('echo hello', shell=True)
```

(Also, the shell will handle splitting up the command for you, so I've used the simpler single-string style of passing the command.)

Comment: Yeah, I tried it this way earlier and it works.  However, the method listed in my original answer is the one listed on the Python website.  Is this because they are referring to the Linux `echo` and not the Windows `echo` ?

Comment: `echo` is an external command on Linux, yeah (though some shells also have an internal version, for performance). I think whoever wrote that did not take Windows into account!