# Why does simple echo in subprocess not working

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I'm trying to perform simple echo operation using subprocess:

```
import subprocess
import shlex

cmd = 'echo $HOME'
proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print proc.communicate()[0]
```

But it prints nothing. Even if I change the command to `echo "hello, world"` it still prints nothing. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It works fine for me. I m using python2.7 on windows 8

Comment: `print os.path.expanduser('~')`

Comment: possible duplicate of [python: why does calling echo with subprocess return WindowsError 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933354/python-why-does-calling-echo-with-subprocess-return-windowserror-2)

Comment: @davelupt: it is *not* a duplicate. Notice: the code in the question *already* uses `shell=True`. It is a different issue that is explained in my answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

On Unix `shell=True` implies that 2nd and following arguments are for the shell itself, use a string to pass a command to the shell:

```
import subprocess

cmd = 'echo $HOME'
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print proc.communicate()[0],
```

You could also write it as:

```
import subprocess

cmd = 'echo $HOME'
print subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True),
```

From [the subprocess' docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html):

> On Unix with `shell=True`, the shell defaults to /bin/sh. If args is a
>   string, the string specifies the command to execute through the shell.
>   This means that the string must be formatted exactly as it would be
>   when typed at the shell prompt. This includes, for example, quoting or
>   backslash escaping filenames with spaces in them. *If args is a
>   sequence, the first item specifies the command string, and any
>   additional items will be treated as additional arguments to the shell
>   itself*. That is to say, Popen does the equivalent of:

```
Popen(['/bin/sh', '-c', args[0], args[1], ...])
```

Comment: Just beware the [security concern](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) about inputting external command with `shell=True`.

Comment: @IsaacS 1- it doesn't apply to a shell command specified as a string literal in your own code 2- the question is about the meaning of subprocess.Popen() arguments  (namely, don't use a list with `shell=True`. It is an error in most cases) 3- otherwise, you don't need to run the external command here at all. Use `print(os.environ['HOME'])` or even `print(Path.home())` (`from pathlib import Path`).

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing the two different invocations of Popen.  Either of these will work:

```
proc=subprocess.Popen(['/bin/echo', 'hello', 'world'], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

or

```
proc=subprocess.Popen('echo hello world', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

When passing shell=True, the first argument is a string--the shell command line.  When not using the shell, the first argument is a list.  Both produce this:

```
print proc.communicate()
('hello world\n', None)
```

Comment: The command from the question has `$HOME` that won't be expanded by your first command.