# Traceback error when using subprocess in Python

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

When trying to use subprocess.check_output, I keep getting this traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    subprocess.check_output(["echo", "Hello World!"])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 537, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 896, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

This even happens when I try:

```
>>>subprocess.check_output(["echo", "Hello World!"])
```

That happens to be the example in the documentation.

Comment: Are you sure `echo` works in Windows?

Comment: Yes, echo works, but it's not that. It happens with ALL commands under subprocess.

Comment: Related(may be): http://stackoverflow.com/a/20335954/846892

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary you were right all along. `echo` isn't an executable on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `ECHO` is built into the Windows `cmd` shell, you can't call it from Python as directly as you would call an executable (or as directly as you would call it on Linux).

i.e. this should work in your system:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output(['notepad'])
```

because notepad.exe is an executable. But in Windows, `echo` can only be called from inside a shell prompt, so the short way to make it work is to use `shell=True`. To keep faith to your code, I would have to write

```
subprocess.check_output(['echo', 'hello world'], shell=True) # Still not perfect
```

(this, following the conditional on line 924 of `subprocess.py` will expand `args` into the full line `'C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /c "echo "hello world""'`, thus calling the `cmd` shell and using the shell's `echo` command)

But, as @J.F.Sebastian kindly pointed out, [for portability a string, and not a list, should be used to pass arguments when using `shell=True`](http://bugs.python.org/issue21347) (check the links to questions on SO there). So the best way to call subprocess.check_output in your case is:

```
subprocess.check_output('echo "hello world"', shell=True)
```

The `args` string is again the correct one, `'C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /c "echo "hello world""'` and your code is more portable.

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) say:

> "On Windows with `shell=True`, the COMSPEC environment variable
>   specifies the default shell. The only time you need to specify
>   `shell=True` on Windows is when the command you wish to execute is built
>   into the shell (e.g. **dir** or **copy**). You do not need `shell=True` to run a
>   batch file or console-based executable.
>
> **Warning:** Passing `shell=True` can be a security hazard if combined with untrusted
>   input. See the warning under *[Frequently Used Arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments)* for details. "

Comment: Aaaand it's a [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933354/python-why-does-calling-echo-with-subprocess-return-windowserror-2). :/ Problem is that I could only find it when I googled for "echo is not a program" + subprocess

Comment: please, [don't use `shell=True` and a list argument together (for portability)](http://bugs.python.org/issue21347), call `check_output('echo "hello world"', shell=True)` instead.